# How to add a bundle manifest to an existing maven dependency?

Tags: maven-2, osgi, manifest, xmp

I am using the Adobe XMP Core dependency within a maven file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.xmp</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmpcore</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The MANIFEST.MF of that bundle is not suited for osgi deployment, as no bundle specific information was provided. So I would need to add the following lines to that Manifest.mf

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Bundle-Version: 5.1.2
Bundle-Name: xmpcore    
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.adobe.xmp.xmpcore
Export-Package: 
 com.adobe.xmp;version="5.1.2",
 com.adobe.xmp.impl;version="5.1.2",
 com.adobe.xmp.impl.xpath;version="5.1.2",
```

Is there a way of unpacking this maven artefact and exchanging the provided manifest via the maven dependency plugin or any different way?

Answer (score 1):

For runtime enhancement use the [Pax URL Wrap Project](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/Wrap+Protocol). If you have this bundle in your environment add the wrap: url-schema to your bundle installation it will auto-wrap your bundle on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Eclipse Virgo Bundlor can do that work for you. 
http://www.eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/bundlor-documentation-1.1.1.RELEASE/docs/user-guide/htmlsingle/user-guide.html#usage.command.line

Virgo Bundlor will add all export-Package statements + all import statements which he can find via declared import-statements in your java-files. If the jar uses dynamic classloading, you need to add a template.mf file with the additional import.